# Is it OK to ask on Meta SE a question of the kind "where do I ask this?"?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Suppose some user has some random question ***Q*** and he doesn't know which S.E. site would be the best fit for the question.

Is it OK for the user to ask "Where does ***Q*** go?" here?

Comment: Why not just ask where you think it best fits? If it needs to be migrated, mods can handle it

Comment: @CarrieKendall It could be that the user doesn't even know if there are candidate sites for the question.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Whatever site you pick may not be aware of what sites it *would* be appropriate on, merely that it's not appropriate on their own site.  Most people are only active on one site, and even those active on more than one are usually only active on a small number, not many sites.  The number of people really active on a significant portion of SE's sites is vanishingly small, and those people are generally found here on meta.SE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed. If you ask a question like that, use the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag. Please read the tag wiki of [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation):

> With the vast openness of the Stack Exchange Network, it can sometimes
>   be confusing where exactly a question is supposed to go. If you are
>   unsure after reading site FAQs, or if you cannot find an existing
>   question here on Meta, consider asking a new question with this tag.
>
> Keep in mind:
>
> - Give an example question you want to ask. If you're going to be vague, it's not going to be the best advice and you may find yourself
>     in rough seas.
> - Not all questions belong on a Q&A site and not everything can find a home here at Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, such questions are appropriate here.  Use the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag when asking these types of questions.